# image segmentation (by graphcut & maxflow) seeds are incorrently labeld

Tags: algorithm, image-segmentation

I have implemented a graphcut algorithm (based on maxflow) for image segmentation (the same idea of [Lazysnapping](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/jiansun/papers/LazySnapping_SIGGRAPH04.pdf)). The algorithm inputs the image and some seeds (both foreground and background). Every pixel (node) will be labeled as foreground or background. However, my algorithm led some foreground seeds with wrong label (labeled as background). And I am confused whether the incorrectly result due to my programming fault.
Does anyone have encountered the same situation? Does the graphcut (maxflow) algorithm make sure the seeds correctly labeled. Where can I find the proof of the algorithm? Is there someone who can give some suggestion to improve my result?
Thanks for your attention and help!

Comment: I am sorry for my poor ability in questioning.
I am not seeking debugging help. My code worked well before with many images. However, I encountered the situation that the seeds incorrectly labeled yesterday. I have searched many websites. And I cannot find the desired information for the situation. The main confusion is whether the algorithm can ensure the seeds to be correctly labeled. Is there any mathematical proof?
Maybe it is not useful for others, and I will close the question. Sorry! And thanks for the answers. I will read the paper for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph cut is an optimization technique. You can read more about it [here](http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~yuri/Papers/pami01.pdf).
The fact that some of your foreground pixels were labeled as "background" is related to the way you impose these foreground/background constraints derived from the interactive seeds you have.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I will read the paper for more information.